# how to set a element's width to be from somewhere specific to the end of the page(horizontally)

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem. I am trying to place some `<div>` elements beside each other. The width of the `div`s are not specified and are dependent on their content. I am using the CSS code below to position the `<div>`s beside each other:

```
#div{
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
}
```

I want the last `<div>`s width to cover the rest of the page (horizontally). With absolute positioning it is possible to set a left position for the last `<div>` and then use `width:100%` for the CSS style. But since I don't know the size of the other `<div>`s, I can not use this approach.

Can anyone help me with my case?

Comment: Are you getting the div element dynamically

Comment: Yes,That is why I cannot know the width of the div s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your browser support needs, you can either use a table-based layout (either with tables or via css) as @user2519211 has shown, or you can use flexbox, which will be much quicker and flexible (ha) in the long run.

You only need to set the container of the elements that you want to cover the page to have `display: flex` (with browser prefixes included)

Here's a JS Bin showing this: http://jsbin.com/uqepit/2/edit

From there you can do any number of things, including reordering, baseline shifting, etc.  If flexbox is an option, Chris Coyer has done some great research on what's currently supported (and behind what syntax).  You can see that here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a table to do this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td style="width: 100%;">asdf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or the `display: table` css declaration if you must use divs:

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">asdf</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">asdf</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">asdf</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%;">asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another question about this. I've heard that for the layouts,we should avoid the tables as much as we can(isn't this true?).And I was hoping for a non-table answer

Comment: In a perfect world, you would use tables solely for displaying rows of data.  Unfortunately, CSS previously provided very few alternatives for positioning flexible-width elements, and so tables were used for positioning elements too.  Technically, there's nothing wrong with it, and it gets the job done, but it's not what it was originally designed for.